# IPtables allow traffic from only an ip and one port to one port

Tags: iptables

I have this command for allow traffic to one port only from one ip:

```
iptables -I INPUT ! -s $BUNGEE_IP -p tcp --dport $PORT -j DROP
```

But I would like allow only a single port of "$BUNGEE_IP", something like this, but dosen't work:

```
iptables -I INPUT ! -s $BUNGEE_IP:$PORT -p tcp --dport $PORT -j DROP
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you want, where 192.168.0.12 represents the IP you want to allow and port 80 the port from that IP you want to allow:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# 1110080_firewall 2019.01.05 Ver:0.01
#       Most basic iptables firewall.
#       Currently for this question:
#       https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110080/iptables-allow-traffic-from-only-an-ip-and-one-port-to-one-port
#

# The location of the iptables program
#
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

#Set some stuff
#
EXTIF="ens5"
UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"

echo 1110080_firewall $FWVER begin.

#Clearing any previous configuration
#
$IPTABLES -P INPUT DROP
$IPTABLES -F INPUT
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F OUTPUT
#$IPTABLES -P FORWARD DROP
$IPTABLES -F FORWARD
#$IPTABLES -t nat -F

# Reset all IPTABLES counters
$IPTABLES -Z

# loopback interfaces are valid.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i lo -s $UNIVERSE -d $UNIVERSE -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -s 192.168.0.12 -p tcp --sport 80 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

#$IPTABLES -A INPUT -j DROP

echo 1110080_firewall $FWVER done.
```